# How to style child's child element when hover over parent

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to style `span .m_12` on hover over `.box_1 img` using `.box_1 img:hover ~ .m_12`.But this seems not working.

```
<div class="col-md-4 box_1"> 
  <a href="#">
    <img src="images/pic1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
  </a>
  <div class="box_2">
    <div class="special-wrap">
       <div class="forclosure2">
         <span class="m_12">$140</span>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is not working? What is the expected and the actual result?

Comment: `img` is not sibling of `.m_12`, that's why it's not working. try `a:hover ~ div .m12` instead

Comment: Where is `.box_1 img`? Please, post your completed code(CSS, html nad etc) or provide a demo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This

```
.box_1 img:hover ~ .m_12
```

will not work because it assumes that `.m_12` is a sibling of the `img` and it isn't.

Hovering can only affect the element being hovered, it's descendents or siblings.

So, you would need.

```
.box_1 a:hover + .box_2 .m_12
```

or

```
.box_1 a:hover ~ .box_2 .m_12
```

In other words, the `.m_12` element is a child/descendant of `.box2` which is a **sibling** of the link `a` which is a child of `.box_1`

Answer (score -1):

use this code:

```
.box_1 img:hover .m_12 {
   /* Write your style */
}
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.